# Global consistency of constraints in a MIP program

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

How does a Mixed Integer Programming (MIP) solver ensure global consistency of constraints while adding an additional constraint (during branch and bound). A naive method would be to add the additional constraint and then compute a feasible solution (if possible). Are there smarter techniques of only adding additional constraints which have no conflict(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understand your question correctly, but adding constraints that lead to infeasibility is not a bad thing.

By doing so, the current node of the branch-and-bound tree can be terminated, which is part of the algorithm. This saves you from exploring a whole lot of nodes that would also be infeasible.